# "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Type' because it is not a delegate type" keeps showing

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

Im trying to build a simple api with .net using EntityFrameworkCore and Identity.I thought I was using a good configuration for my relationships but now the error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Type' because it is not a delegate type" keeps showing where nothing appeared before.
This is the code im using on this entity:

```
    public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Country).WithMany(x => x.ApplicationUsers).HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Gender).WithMany(x => x.ApplicationUsers).HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);

    }
}
```

I don't know what else to do. I would be very grateful if you could help.
I have a public repo with all the code, dont be afraid to take a look in case you need.https://github.com/nachocebey/Site

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This code will not throw the error you describe. Which line is the problem? What does `ApplicationUser` look like? How about `Country` or `Gender`?

Comment: Looking at your Github repo though, `x.Country` is an `int` but  it should be a `CountryEntity`

Comment: Yes! I thought i changed it. Thanks